# SQL: Take only the latest entry for each "group"?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Here I created some table to test with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `index` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `index2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `somenumber` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`,`index2`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`index`, `index2`, `date`, `somenumber`) VALUES
('kevin', 'little', '2013-06-11', 1),
('kevin', 'little', '2013-07-03', 5),
('maria', 'smith', '2013-07-01', 3),
('martin', 'luther', '2013-07-04', 13),
('martin', 'luther', '2013-07-05', 14);
```

Now I want to get the **latest** `somenumber` for everyone, ordered by `somenumber DESC`. Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` GROUP BY `index`, `index2` ORDER BY `somenumber` DESC
```

The problem is that this query does always take one somenumber for every group, but it's not always the latest.

(I know the indexnames don't make too much sense here, but I thought it would be an easier-to-read example than using random number-indexes)

Comment: if u want the latest record inserted, shudnt u just leave it as `ORDER BY somenumber;`

Comment: You mean latest by date?

Comment: Yes, I want the latest number for everyone where "latest" is defined by the `date` row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.`INDEX`, t1.`INDEX2`, t1.`SOMENUMBER` FROM TEST t1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT `INDEX`, `INDEX2`, MAX(`DATE`) DATE FROM TEST
GROUP BY `INDEX`, `INDEX2`) t2 ON t1.INDEX = t2.INDEX AND t1.INDEX2 = t2.INDEX2 AND t1.DATE = t2.DATE
```

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'INDEX' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: I have now tested both answers in a pretty big sample database and this query is so much faster. Marked this as correct answer now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT * FROM `test`  ORDER BY `index`, `date` DESC) as temp
GROUP BY `index`, `index2` 
ORDER BY `somenumber` DESC
```

Comment: In the outer query, "[the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html)".

Comment: In the outer query, the server will choose the first value for each group. Since rows are sorted by "ORDER BY `index`, `date` DESC", so it will take the newest row.

Comment: Please explain how you have determined that "the server will choose the first value for each group" when the documentation says otherwise?  Please explain how you have determined what is the "first value" when the documentation makes no assertions about ordering being carried from materialised tables into parent queries?